# Selenium: Set Proxy server for Firefox and IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Using Selenium Grid I want to specify the proxy server.

Current code:

```
caps = {
  "proxy": {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": "104.199.70.128:30687",
    "sslProxy": "104.199.70.128:30687"
  },
... }
```

I got this error

```
WebDriverError: cannot create session firefox on any hosts after 1 attempt(s), last host error was: InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
```

Works fine with chrome and opera.

Comment: Issues? Exceptions? Logs?

Comment: check update for error message

Comment: Post the complete code that you have used